# Magento Admin Grid - How to assign an action/function to a button?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I created a new module and I managed to list all the orders from the shop.
I also added a button (with this code).

```
$link= Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/order/sync/') .'id/$entity_id';

$this->addColumn('action_edit', array(
'header'   => $this->helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
'width'    => 15,
'sortable' => false,
'filter'   => false,
'type'     => 'action',
'actions'  => array(
    array(
        'url'     => $link,
        'caption' => $this->helper('catalog')->__('Sync'),
    ),
)
));
```

I really don't know how to assign an action to this button. What I should create in my custom module ? A new controller?

I need to display something or get some data when I click this button...

thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should write

```
public function YourActionNameAction()
{
}
```

in your Module controller file

Comment: thank you ! but how can I parse variables from the grid?

Comment: $req_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); put this line in your action this will give you entity id